# Change value in form with readonly_fields field when creating an object

Tags: django

```
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PostFormAdmin
    readonly_fields = ['author']

class PostFormAdmin(PostValidationMixin, forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'


author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=False, default=1)
```

Since the field is readonly_fields, it is always default
Before I submit the form, I need to substitute request.user there

I want to understand at what stage it is possible to assign request.user so that the user sees himself in the form and not the default user